# How to know which devices my switch is connected to if my computer is connected to the switch via a router?

Tags: networking, command-line, router, switch

My computer is connected to a router and my router is connected to a switch. Is it possible to see the MAC IDs of the devices which the switch is connected to from my computer **[Switch-->Router-->Computer]**. I think it is not possible just asking out of curiosity.

Comment: If it's a managed switch that you can make a connection to from your computer, you probably can. Alternately, some routers can show you what MAC addresses are routed through which physical ports; you can use that to determine what is connected to the switch if you know which port the switch is on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computer is connected on the LAN side of the router then yes, you can see the MAC addresses, if its connected to the WAN port then you can't.

(While its possible to the router is fancy and doing stuff below the IP level, most don't in which case) you can test this using traceroute.  If the computer sees the other devices directly then it will see MAC addresses, but if it sees the router in the traceroute then it won't - MAC addresses don't traverse a routed connection.

Comment: Okay, I did it while my computer is connected to router via the LAN port, but it didn't work. I think my router is doing some fancy stuffs as you said. :-)